# C# alternative to Visual Basic .NET namespace My

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm a VB.NET programmer, but I'm new to C# and now I'm working with C# project which uses local resource files (.resx).

Using VB.NET I can access to variables in resource file via **My**.Resources.< LocalResourceFile >.< MyVariable > . But in C# I can't find any alternatives for **My** namespace, but I still can access to resource if I replace **My** namespace with < MyProjectNamespace >.

Maybe there are any other way to access my local resources?

Comment: There is no such thing in C#.

Comment: You can use (most of) the My namespace's convenience classes from c# if you wish: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you absolutely *must* use the equivalent of the `My` namespace, there is actually such a thing in C#. It is the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.MyServices` namespace. To use that, you must add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;` to your code file. For this route, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136.aspx

I would not, however recommend doing that. Instead, to access resources, you simply use `MyNamespace.Properties.Resources` like this:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
...
    var myFile = SomeNamespace.Properties.Resources.MyFile;
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this which is virtually the equivalent:

```
Bitmap image = Properties.Resources.picture000;
```

Answer (score 2):

It still works the same way, just don't put "My.Resources" in front of the name.  So if you added a .resx file named "Resource1" and put a string named "Foo" in the resource then the variable name is "Resource1.Foo".

If you put code in non-default namespaces then you may have to prefix it with the default project namespace.  Like "WindowsFormsApplication1.Resource1.Foo".  If you are lost then just look at the auto-generated code.  In the Solution Explorer window open the node next to the .resx file and double-click the Designer.cs file.  Don't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in `My` namespace, but you can reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and have it.

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136(v=vs.80).aspx